# Qt/C++ Execute Commands on a Remote Machine & Interact with its Prompts

Tags: c++, qt, ssh, stdin

I am developing a C++ program using the Qt 5 Framework and need to do the following:

1. Connect to a remote server using SSH
2. Execute commands like mkdir ~/testing
3. Execute commands like mysqldump -u test -p123 testdb -> testdb.sql

Basically the standard commands you would run as if you were using the terminal.

I looked into QProcess but it is limited and I don't feel comfortable using echo "password" | ssh -x hostname -l username, etc...

Is there any C++ or Qt library that can do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Check if *ssh* can take password (or preferably a pass phrase for private key) from an environment variable. That is a clean way to pass values you do not want accidentally stored to some .bash_history or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that fits my needs. If I do come up with a solution that is cross platform I will let you guys know. Here's how to make it work in QT on a Linux enviornment.

```
QStringList commands;
commands << "-hold";
commands << "-e";
commands << "ssh username@host 'cd /home/user/backups; mysqldump -u root -p mydb > mydb.sql; echo DONE!'";

QProcess *process = new QProcess(0);
process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
process->start("xterm", commands);

if(!process->waitForStarted()){
    qDebug() << "Could not wait to start...";
}

if(!process->waitForFinished()) {
    qDebug() << "Could not wait to finish...";
}

process->closeWriteChannel();
qDebug() << process->readAll();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should learn how to configure `ssh` (with public keys) without any password (or just a passphrase added with [ssh-add](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/ssh-add/) before starting your Qt application). Read some good [ssh tutorial](http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux). Then use [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/) and/or [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/) etc...

Comment: It did cross my mind but I think it's more secure to prompt for password. Not sure why there isn't a suitable solution yet... I think it's a common problem among many developers.

Comment: You really should learn much more about `ssh`. I don't understand why you believe that a long passphrase given thru `ssh-add` is less secure than a shorter password given at every `ssh` connection.

Comment: The main issue is not SSH actually. If you look at what I am trying to accomplish you will see that I will be running the mysqldump command. I do not want to pipe the mysql database password either. I needed a way for the system to handle password prompts made by the remote server. The xterm window allows me to sequence all my commands and input or respond to them when I need to. The SSH was really a very small part of the main issue, I needed to know how I could interact with a remote shell from my Qt App. Thanks for your effort though :)